# Trying to test method is called in a subscription but it's never triggered

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I have a method that is called in an ngOnInit. I want to test that given the ngOnInit call then `this.anotherService.methodToCall()` is triggered and what it is being called with.

It just never seems to be called when I run my tests. I've tried several different ways to try and do this but nothing seems to work. I'm pretty new working with Angular and observables so I might be missing something very obvious.

The functionality of the component does exactly what I want it to do. So i'm basically just asking on advice on what the best method to test this would be. Thanks.

In component.ts

```
readOnly items: Observable<TemplateItems[]> = this.itemsHandler.itemsState$;
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.checkParams();
}
```

```
private checkParams() : void {
  this.observableResult$ = combineLatest(this.items, this.activatedRoute.params]);
  this.subscriptions.add(
    this.observableResult$.subscribe(([items, params]) => {
      // During tests I never get this far
      this.anotherService.methodToCall(items, params); 
    )
  )
}
```

in spec.ts - This is an example of the sorta thing I would like to do but once again not sure if this is the best way to approach.

```
...
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      RouterTestingModule,
      ...,
    ],
    providers: [
      AnotherService,
      {
        provide: ActivatedRoute,
        useValue: {
          params: of({}),
        } 
      }
    ]
  }).compileComponents()
});
...

describe('ngOnInit', () => {
  it('should call anotherservice methodcall with filter items and params', fakeAsync (() => {
    activedRoute.params = of ({ value: "TEST_VALUE"});

    fixture.detectChanges();
    ...
    tick();

    expect(spyOfAnotherServiceMethodCall).toBeCalledWith(someItemsValue, { value: "TEST_VALUE"})
  }
}))
```

Comment: Can you please show the code before the `tick()`, it will give us a better understanding of the case. And also - could you add a `console.log` in the `ngOnInit` method and another `console.log` before the `activedRoute.params` call and share which one is called first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `tick` function (https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried with the tick() function in there but it didn't help anything. I'll update the original post with the tick.